# Java object wrapper

Tags: java, wrapper

I have a WS ( CarASessionBean )it will call another WS ( CarBProxy ) to create a car details. So inside my CarASessionBean WS has a method call createCar :
 (In proxy has the same method as well call createCar just it take in CarB object  as parameter).

```
public void createCar(CarA car) { 
     //here i will call the proxy and here error occur as CarBProxy take in CarB object
     ...
     **carBProxy.createCar(car);**
}
```

In this case is it possible to use wrapper? I just heard about wrapper not much understand what wrapper can do, can rougly guide me how to use wrapper i had reseached through google most example is about primitive type I was wonder is there possible to use wrapper to convert an object to another object. Example from CarA to CarB?

Answer (score 3):

This is referred to as the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).  Depending on the circumstances there's no reason you can't design CarB to wrap a CarA object.  However, if you have two preexisting (non interface) classes CarB and CarA, converting one to another is going to be more than just a wrapper. Can you be a little more precise about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Adapter Pattern is a design pattern (i.e. a concept, not an actual piece of software).  This is made clear in the very first sentence of the Wikipedia page I linked to.  I suggest you look at it.

Comment: is basically to create an interface and implements it? correct me if i am wrong as I researched from google this is what i understnad

Answer (score 0):

You could, but you'd be writing this wrapper yourself. There isn't anything built into standard Java that will do this for you. Something interesting in the Eclipse APIs is the [IAdaptable](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/what-is-iadaptable/) interface which may be a pattern you want to use for this.